# Bootstrap Date Time Picker No Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have followed the example given at http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/# to the letter.

Im trying to do *disabling dates in the past and dependent disabling.*

You can [view my JSFIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/leela89/a4qdzq63/#&togetherjs=Kb5rjafSso).

This is my head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker/css/datepicker.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Below Is my Code as per the example:

```
<script>
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
      onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
      }
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
      if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
      }
      checkin.hide();
      $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
    }).data('datepicker');
    var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
      onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
      }
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
      checkout.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
</script>

<input type="text" id="dpd1" value="" class="span2">
<input type="text" id="dpd2" value="" class="span2">
```

My problem...Well the browser, neither firefox - firebug or chrome are displaying any errors, however when I click on text field it is unresponsive i.e. nothing happens. I can confirm datepicker.js & css are linked correctly as verified by dreamweaver.

Not really sure what I am missing here, perhaps I didn't get something in the tutorial, if anyone could give this a quick scan would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your jsfiddle you have links to the wrong libraries. You can start with fixing that.

Comment: @Dekel Would you mind making a suggestion to which lib is linked wrong, since I honestly dont see which lib is linked incorrectly, hench me adding my lib section in the question

Comment: You have a link there to `datetimepicker`, while you use `datepicker`

Comment: @Dekel would you mind giving it a look now...I linked to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.uk.min.js`

Comment: I still see the `datetimepicker` in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never called datepicker

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker() 
   //now do your stuff
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    :
    :`